# How to get data from API and turn it into array list for Google Charts

Tags: reactjs, axios, bar-chart

I'm pretty new to React and am currently trying to use the [Nasa neo API](https://api.nasa.gov/) to feed data into a react google chart.

The problem is when i send a get request with axios i end up with loads nested data objects that i somehow have to convert to a array to use with google charts.

```js
class MainPage extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [['name', 'max estimated diameter', 'min estimated diameter']]
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY')

      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ data: response });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

this is what i have so far, i'm guessing i need to map through the data but everything i've tried so far doesn't seem to work.

anyone know how i should proceed ?

or got any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Axios, your `get` request will return an object with `data` key.

```js
.then(({data}) => { // destructure data from response object
    // {name, estimated_diameter} from data
    const restructuredData = data.near_earth_objects.map(({name, estimated_diameter}) => 
        [name, estimated_diameter.metrics. estimated_diameter_max, estimated_diameter.metrics.estimated_diameter_min])

    this.setState({data: restructuredData});
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})
```

Axios response schema for your reference https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

Comment: Yeap, that seems to work but now my old state gets removed instead of getting added to it.

Comment: Right, then you'd just have to spread your initial state into the new state. `this.setState({data: [...this.state.data, ...restructuredData]});`

Answer (score 0):

From the [swagger documentation](https://api.nasa.gov/neo/?api_key=DEMO_KEY#!/rest%2Fv1%2Fneo/browseNearEarthObjects) I can see that the endpoint `/neo/browse` returns something like this:

```
{
  "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid": true,
  "is_sentry_object": true,
  "neo_reference_id": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "name_limited": "string",
  "designation": "string",
  "nasa_jpl_url": "string",
  "absolute_magnitude_h": 0,
  "estimated_diameter": {},
  "close_approach_data": [
    {
      "close_approach_date_full": "string",
      "close_approach_date": "string",
      "epoch_date_close_approach": 0,
      "relative_velocity": {},
      "miss_distance": {},
      "orbiting_body": "string"
    }
  ],
  "orbital_data": {},
  "sentry_data": "string"
}
```

This is a JSON so what you want to do is getting the fields and then save them in your state.

From the [google react chart api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-charts) I see we want data to be an array of arrays, like this:

```js
const data = [
  ["Column1", "Column2"],
  ["row1_column1", "row1_column2"],
  ["row2_column1", "row2_column2"],
// ...
];
```

What I would do is:

```js
      .then(response => {
        this.state.data
        this.setState({
            data: [
                ...this.state.data
                [
                    response.data.name,
                    response.data.estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_max,
                    response.data.estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_min
                ]
            ]
        })
```

Basically we are appending a new array with the three values we want to the already existing data. To extract the values from the JSON we have received from the API we just need to look at the response we receive by trying out the API on swagger.

Also remember that `setState()` is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous).

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help you...

```
<Chart
  data={[
    ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'],
    ...array.map(d => [ d.column1, d.column2, d.column3 ])
  ]}
/>
```